# Issue fetching into SYS_REFCURSOR out variable from stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

My purpose is to fetch data in the output variable "c" of the stored procedure. This variable is of type SYS_REFCURSOR. But I am having issues. It says: "results do not match with query".

Here is the code

```
PROCEDURE SP_BUSCAR_AL(VE_PROGRAM               IN VARCHAR2,
                             VE_TIPO_CAMPO_ESTUDIO  IN NUMBER,
                             VE_CODE_ESCUELA    IN VARCHAR2,
                             VE_NOMBRE_ALTERNATIVA  IN VARCHAR2,
                             c OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
BEGIN
DECLARE

VL_PROGRAM             VARCHAR2(100);
VL_TIPO_CAMPO_ESTUDIO  NUMBER;
VL_CODE_ESCUELA        VARCHAR2(100);
VL_NOMBRE_ALTERNATIVA  VARCHAR2(100);
aa SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN

  VL_PROGRAM                := VE_PROGRAM;
  VL_TIPO_CAMPO_ESTUDIO     := VE_TIPO_CAMPO_ESTUDIO;
  VL_CODE_ESCUELA     := VE_CODE_ESCUELA;
  VL_NOMBRE_ALTERNATIVA     := VE_NOMBRE_ALTERNATIVA;


  BEGIN
     OPEN aa FOR
       SELECT stvmjr.stvmajr_code,stvmjr.stvmajr_desc
        FROM smrprle,
             sobcurr,
             sorccon,
             stvmajr stvmjr,
             govsdav
        WHERE  
             govsdav_pk_parenttab = stvmajr_code 
             AND stvmajr_code = sorccon_majr_code_conc  
             AND sorccon_curr_rule = sobcurr_curr_rule 
             AND sobcurr_program = smrprle_program 
             AND govsdav_table_name LIKE '%STVMAJR%' 
             AND govsdav_attr_name = 'TIPO_CAMPO_ESTUDIO' 
             AND govsdav_value_as_char = 1
             AND smrprle_program = VL_PROGRAM
             ; 

loop
fetch aa into c; --It says results do not match here
exit when aa%notfound;
end loop;

END SP_BUSCAR_AL;
```

I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cursor is simply a reference to a SELECT statement which has been opened. You need to fetch the results of the cursor into appropriate variables so you can use them. So let's update your procedure to do this:

```
PROCEDURE SP_BUSCAR_AL(VE_PROGRAM  IN  VARCHAR2
                       c           OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN c FOR
    SELECT stvmjr.stvmajr_code,stvmjr.stvmajr_desc
      FROM smrprle,
           sobcurr,
           sorccon,
           stvmajr stvmjr,
           govsdav
      WHERE govsdav_pk_parenttab = stvmajr_code 
        AND stvmajr_code = sorccon_majr_code_conc  
        AND sorccon_curr_rule = sobcurr_curr_rule 
        AND sobcurr_program = smrprle_program 
        AND govsdav_table_name LIKE '%STVMAJR%' 
        AND govsdav_attr_name = 'TIPO_CAMPO_ESTUDIO' 
        AND govsdav_value_as_char = 1
        AND smrprle_program = VE_PROGRAM;     
END SP_BUSCAR_AL;
```

I eliminated all the unused parameters, and the local variables which also weren't used.

Now, when using this procedure you should first call the procedure, and the loop over the cursor to fetch the results and then use them:

```
DECLARE
  CSR           SYS_REFCURSOR;
  stvMajr_code  STVMAJR%STVMAJR_CODE%TYPE;
  stvMajr_desc  STVMAJR%STVMAJR_DESC%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SP_BUSCAR_AL(VE_PROGRAM => 'some value',
               c          => CSR);

  LOOP
    FETCH CSR
      INTO stvMajr_code,
           stvMajr_desc;
    EXIT WHEN CSR%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CODE=''' || stvMajr_code ||
                         '''  DESC=''' || stvMajr_desc || '''');
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Share and enjoy;

Comment: In this case, you have to declare all the columns. Do we have the faster ways? for example, l_cur CSR%rowtype?

Comment: Nope. A SYS_REFCURSOR doesn't have a rowtype because there's no static field information, so you have to use a FETCH...INTO.

Answer (score 3):

Ref Cursors are not variables, they're pointers.  So we cannot fetch into them.

In your situation all you need to do is use the OUT parameter when you open the cursor...

```
OPEN c FOR
   SELECT stvmjr.stvmajr_code,stvmjr.stvmajr_desc
```

Alternatively you could just assign it...

```
c := aa;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @APC I just need to add more cursors (pointers) to c, at least two more. I want to group and asign all these cursors(pointers) into one (c). I only thought of this.